# Closure of a set in arrow topology.

Tags: general-topology

I have to find the closure of a set in topological space $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{\leftarrow}\right)$. Set is defined as:

> $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2i+1},\frac{1}{2i}\right)$

Can you give me any hints?

Comment: What is the arrow topology?

Comment: @KevinLong This is the topology where the base is given by all intervals (a,b], where a<b.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\frac1{2i}$ is in the closure for all $i\ge1$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\frac{1}{2i+1}$? Because then I can't find any open set (in the complement) from base with this point and which is a subset of the complement.

Comment: It's a bit tricky. The open sets are countable union of disjoint intervals $(a, b] $, infinities included, just as in the usual topology. Their complements are again unions of $(a, b] $ intervals.

Comment: Nevertheless, any neighborhood of $\frac1{2i}$ contains some parts *to the left*, i.e. it intersects $(\frac1{2i+1},\frac1{2i}) $.

Comment: Ok, now, I think that I see the solution. Thank you for the help!